# Proper method to hash an arbitrary object

Tags: hash, md5, go

I am writing a data structure that needs to hash an arbitrary object.  The following function seems to fail if I give an `int` is the parameter.

```
func Hash( obj interface{} ) []byte {
    digest := md5.New()
    if err := binary.Write(digest, binary.LittleEndian, obj); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return digest.Sum()
}
```

Calling this on an `int` results in:

> panic: binary.Write: invalid type int

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I found that a good way to do this is to serialize the object using the "gob" package, along the following lines:

```
var (
    digest = md5.New()
    encoder = gob.NewEncoder(digest)
)

func Hash(obj interface{}) []byte {
    digest.Reset() 
    if err := encoder.Encode(obj); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return digest.Sum()
}
```

Edit: This does not work as intended (see below).

Comment: Yep, this is probably the way to go.

Comment: There are some problems with your implementation. First, the gob protocol transmits the type definition whenever you encode a new type and refers to it later by ID. So, your Hash() method returns a different hash when used for the first time. And second those global variables might lead to race conditions, which also be the cause for different hashes.

Comment: tux21b is correct about gob (though thread-safety wasn't intended).

Answer (score 2):

[binary.Write](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Write) writes "a fixed-size value or a pointer to a fixed-size value." Type [int](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Numeric_types) is not a fixed size value; int is "either 32 or 64 bits." Use a fixed-size value like int32.

Comment: Yep.  So what do to in this case?

Comment: You could do something like: foo := uint32(123); binary.Write(buffer, order, foo) or binary.Write(buffer, order, uint32(foo)), or use other similar lines.